# The relative virtual path is not allowed here

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

In my controller action, I have the following code:

```
...more code

if (...)
{
    // create a site user
    await this.CreateUserAndSignHimInAsync(UserType.SiteUser, model);

    var landingPageUrl = IdentityManager.GetLandingPageUrl(model.Email);

    return Redirect(landingPageUrl);
}

...more code
```

The `landingPageUrl` is a url that looks like so: **"~/Journal/Search".**

At the `return Redirect` line, I get an exception that says:

> The relative virtual path '~Journal/Search' is not allowed here.

Comment: It's the MVC `Controller.Redirect` method that returns a `RedirectResult`. I think I am close to finding out the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with my code was that the URL that I was trying to redirect to, as reported by the exception message, was an ill-formed **~Journal/Search** instead of **~/JournalSearch**.

Also, I discovered that if you have an ASP.NET virtual relative URL like "~/Journal/Search" and you would like to turn it into an absolute Url, you can call the `UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl` static method like so:

```
var url= UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl("~/Journal/Search", 
         Request.RequestContext.HttpContext);
```